# Bibtex Error message

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I'm new to latex and Ive been having some trouble making a bibliography in my latex document. To test it I made a new document with the following code

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\begin{document}
Article \cite{greenwade93} and \cite{DrineasPetros2016Rrnl}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Heres my bib file:

```
@article{greenwade93,
    author  = "George D. Greenwade",
    title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",    
year    = "1993",
journal = "TUGBoat",
volume  = "14",
number  = "3",
pages   = "342--351"
}

@article{DrineasPetros2016Rrnl,
issn = "0001-0782",
abstract = "<p><p>Randomization offers new benefits for large-scale linear 
algebra computations.</p></p>",
journal = "Communications of the ACM",
pages = "80--90",
volume = "59",
publisher = "ACM",
number = "6",
year = "2016",
title = "RandNLA: randomized numerical linear algebra",
language = "eng",
author = "Drineas, Petros and Mahoney, Michael",
keywords = "Engineering ; Computer Science ; Mathematics",
month = "May",
}
```

This works perfectly and does exactly what I want it to, however if I put this exact same code in the document I'm working on it throws up an error when bibtex runs.

[image: error message]

If you could help me find what the problem is I would appreciate it.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please do not paste code as images, but as code. Have you tried deleting the aux file?

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit it and put the code in. I tried deleting the Aux file and it didn't make any difference.

Comment: you show `\bibliographystyle{plain}` but the error message is about `apalike` which suggests you have `\bibliography{apalike}` somewhere in your file.

Comment: Thankyou so much! Im such an idiot haha, turns out I already had the bibliography style in my preamble without realising. Once I removed it, it works fine. Sorry for asking a stupid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you show

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
```

but the error message is about `apalike` which suggests you have

```
\bibliography{apalike}
```

somewhere earlier in your document.